# Problems with a file upload MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I had a problem with file upload.
Here is my controller

```
    public class StoreManagerController : Controller
    {
    private StoreContext db = new StoreContext();

    //Some actions here

    //
    // POST: /StoreManager/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Book book, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            book.CoverUrl = UploadCover(file, book.BookId);
            db.Books.Add(book);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AuthorId = new SelectList(db.Authors, "AuthorId", "Name", book.AuthorId);
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", book.GenreId);
        ViewBag.PublisherId = new SelectList(db.Publishers, "PublisherId", "Name", book.PublisherId);
        return View(book);
    }

    private string UploadCover(HttpPostedFileBase file, int id)
    {
        string path = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif";
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (fileExt == "png" || fileExt == "jpg" || fileExt == "bmp")
            {
                var img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream) as Bitmap;
                path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Covers/") + id + ".jpg";
                img.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }

        return path;
    }
}
```

My Create View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "StoreManager", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @/* divs here */@
    <div class="editor-label">
        Cover
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

When I try upload a file, I got a default placeholder. So I think the post data is null.
But when I inspected it with browser I got the next post data

```
------WebKitFormBoundary5PAA6N36PHLIxPJf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please reduce the code in your question so that it only contains code that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I can see that is wrong is this conditional:

```
if (fileExt == "png" || fileExt == "jpg" || fileExt == "bmp")
```

This will never return `true`, because `Path.GetExtension` includes a '.' in the file extension. It sounds like this might be your main problem as this will simply skip the conditional block and you'll be left with your placeholder. This will need to be changed to:

```
if (fileExt == ".png" || fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".bmp")
```

However, there is so much code in your question that it's difficult to determine whether this is the only problem.

If you still have problems, I would suggest placing a breakpoint in your controller action (you haven't specified whether this is `Edit` or `Create` and checking whether the value of `file` is as expected. You should be able to isolate where the problem is from there and - if you still can't resolve it - will at least be able to narrow your question down a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem was with that condition. And one more question. Can you give me a link for the asp.net mvc code debugging. I can't releize how I can debug it.

Comment: It's quite straight forward. If you run your app in Debug mode (usually F5), you can simply place breakpoints in your application and check the values of variables and object properties at runtime. Read here for more info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn